# Using html+css+javascript or JSP as my presentation layer

Tags: javascript, mysql, eclipse, spring, jsp

I want to build an application which contains a basic menu (with, lets say 10 buttons), each button is a subject in my girlfriend's psychology course. when i click a button, i will be transfer to the specific subject's menu. (so i have 10 sub-menus like this).

In each sub menu, i can press buttons as well, but this time i wil get some sentences which i saved in mySql data base.

I know how to build the most of the server side part using spring (i know how to build the controllers and service layer) hibernate part (i know how to build the domains and DAO layer),

My problem is, that i don't know if i should use html+css+java script in order to build the menus and configure the functionality and communication between the controller and the client, or maybe  should i use Jsp+Jstl?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, i know this is quiet fundamental..

Comment: There's no "should", whether you should use a client-side framework or do most of the work in JSP, or a combination of both (the most likely) is a requirements decision, not a technical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using jstl tags you can build

like

```
 <c:out value="${name}"/>
```

Comment: Or just `${name}` in any reasonable container.

Comment: @DaveNewton I recommend you look at c:out doc. They are not equivalent... Hint: escaping.

Comment: @AdamGent Yes, I'm aware of that. Thanks for the "hint".

Comment: I didn't mean to sound snide.... I just didn't want the OP to introduce XSS vulnerability.